# Newtosoft.Json | API

Tags: c#, json, api

Никак не пойму, в чем может быть ошибка. Прошу взглянуть:

```
var get = new HttpRequest();

string getgive = get.Get("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22").ToString();

dynamic json = JObject.Parse(getgive);
JToken userid = json;
string last = json["country"];
richTextBox1.Text = "Страна: " + last;
```

Если в место "country" ввести "name" - то все выводит из JSON схемы которую мы получили, но если вывести "country" - то оно не выводиться, хотя есть в схеме точно так же как и "name".

Пробовал даже с API VK
Пример:

```
var get = new HttpRequest();

string getgive = get.Get("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=1&v=5.52").ToString();

dynamic json = JObject.Parse(getgive);
JToken userid = json.["last_name"];

richTextBox1.Text = "Фамилия: " + userid;
```

Не выводит он фамилия, хотя "last_name" в схеме есть.

Никак не могу понять ошибку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скажите, а где вы видите `country`? Я вам даже визуализирую ваши данные:

[image: siteOne]

А где вы видите `last_name`?

[image: siteTwo]

Вот у вас есть папка на диске `C`, скажем `Мои видео`, она в свою очередь находиться в папке `Разное`. Вот вам надо открыть `Мои видео`, вы будете в адресной строке так и писать? Нет! Вы же обязаны будете написать **полный** путь до указанной директории, то есть `C:\Разное\Мои видео`, не как не `Мои видео`.

Тот же пример можно взять к примеру, к сайту VK. Вот вам надо открыть аудиозаписи, вы что напишите в адресной строке `https://vk.com/audios1234` или `audios1234`? Думаю ответ очевиден.

Ну а теперь интересное, вы не поверите, но в `JSON` работают точно такие же правила! Вы не можете взять `country`, который в свою очередь находиться в `sys`, вам нужно указывать полный путь, то есть в вашем случае это `["sys"]["country"]`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь длинное объяснение,
Не подскажете что у Вас за программа такая, которая вот так вот структуру выводит?

Comment: @L9mur На здоровье. Это [данный](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) сайт.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень выручил )